# First Exception program

Tags: java, exception

Here's the first exception coding I've ever done and guess what, it's generating an error. Sad.

```
public class Exc {
int x = 2;
public void throwE(int p) throws Excp { 
    if(x==p) {
        throw new Excp();
    }
  }
}
```

I don't think I need to post the handler code as even this class isn't getting through compiler.

I'm getting the error `cannot find symbol` at `Excp`. I'm doing exactly according book. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably missing an `Excp` class. Try replacing Excp with Exception, for starters.

Comment: um.. that worked. But please, can you explain what I was doing wrong. I mean, what's wrong with the name of the exception?

Comment: An exception needs to exist.  Did you want the class itself to be the exception, then you need to spell it the same.

Comment: `Excp` is not a class from the Java Standard Library. `Exception` is. If you want to throw your own exception, such as `Excp` or `MyException` or `WhateverNameYouWant` you have to create such class and it has to extend `Exception` class. You can do so creating a new class like this: `public class MyException extends Exception { //here the implementation}`

Comment: Your class is called `Exc` but you are throwing an `Excp`, so the compiler can't find anything actually called `Excp` and is complaining.

Comment: All of you, Thanks a lot. Got It!